# Node debug: watch expression yields different result from exec console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

I'm implementing my own Promise A+ compatible package just for the fun. While testing it, and error came accross and I'm having a bad time to solve it.

I'm trying to test it against the [Promise A+ Test Suite](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-tests). The test cases that are causing the issue are all that test "If/when `y` is a thenable for a thenable..." (described [here](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-tests/blob/master/lib/tests/2.3.3.js#L319)).

Here is the description of the first failing test:

> Promise Promises/A+ Test 2.3.3: Otherwise, if `x` is an object or function, 2.3.3.3: If `then` is a function, call it with `x` as `this`, first argument `resolvePromise`, and second argument `rejectPromise` 2.3.3.3.1: If/when `resolvePromise` is called with value `y`, run `[[Resolve]](promise, y)` `y` is a thenable for a thenable `y` is an already-fulfilled promise for a synchronously-fulfilled custom thenable `then` calls `resolvePromise` synchronously via return from a fulfilled promise

This is how I wrote my adapter:

```
var adapter = (function() {
    var res, rej;
    return {
        defered: {
            promise: new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                res = resolve;
                rej = reject;
            }),
            resolve: res,
            reject: rej,
        }
    }
})();

describe("Promises/A+ Tests", function () {
    require("promises-aplus-tests").mocha(adapter);
});
```

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/hbarcelos/2aa771eafe646b5cd504) for the full implementation. The issue is happening on the following part:

```
Promise.prototype.then = function(onFulfill, onReject) {
    let p = new Promise();

    debugger;
    let pending = {
        fulfill: isFunction(onFulfill) ? onFulfill : v => v,
        reject: isFunction(onReject) ? onReject : e => { throw e },
        promise: p,
    };

    this.queue.push(pending);

    run.call(this);

    return p;
};
```

Here's when the oddities begin. One of the tests tries to assess that when a promise yields a promise to a promise, it will be fulfilled with the same value.

I'm getting some strange errors, so I tried to debug it all the way.

What is going on: when the debugger reach the breakpoint in the code above, `watch` is behaving weirdly.

If I run `watch('onFulfill')`, `watchers` will give me:

```
0: onFulfill = undefined
```

But if I do `exec console.log(onFulfill)`, it will print:

```
< [Function: onBasePromiseFulfilled]
```

What is going on here?

### Edit:

When stopped in the `debugger` statement, having created the `p` variable, if I type:

```
> p
```

in the debugger console, It gives me:

```
< { state: State('pending'), queue: [] }
```

But if I try to do:

```
> exec console.log(p)
```

The program crashes, giving me a termination error.

Comment: It would be helpful to let us know which test is causing the problem.

Comment: I've editted the question explaining which ones.

Comment: Can you provide any more info about the termination error?

Comment: That's the problem! There is no error description at all, it just says that the execution was terminated.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this but your adapter doesn't look like what they describe in the readme: adapter.deferred should be a function. After modifying your adapter I managed to debug it using node-inspector

Comment: In deed, you are right. I've missed that. But it's still strange that a high-level language such as Javascript giving me termination errors like that. I'll try to create a propper adapter later today. Even this doesn't this specific problem, my main goal was to make my library pass the test suite, so I'd happily award you the bounty if you make your comment an answer. Thank, you @ekuusela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this but your adapter doesn't look like what they describe in [the readme](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-tests): `adapter.deferred` should be a function. After modifying your adapter I managed to debug it using node-inspector.

Even after fixing the adapter, I did get some weird behaviour with mocha debug console but it's my first time debugging with node/mocha so I don't know if it's actually weird. No termination errors, but trying to `console.log` some definitely defined variables came out as undefined.

Also, without modifying the adapter, running the tests failed almost immediately with a clear error message. Se we probably were running the tests differently or something was different with our setups if you didn't get that.

Here's the adapter I used:

```
var adapter = (function() {
    var res, rej;
    return {
        deferred: function() { 
            return {
                promise: new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                    res = resolve;
                    rej = reject;
                }),
                resolve: res,
                reject: rej,
            };
        }
    }
})();
```